# Helper method with the same name as partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, helper, renderpartial

I have a helper with a method named `search_form` like this:

```
module Admin::BaseHelper
  def search_form(*args)
    # my great code here
  end
end
```

To call this method in my HAML code, I can do this:

```
= search_form
= search_form()
= search_form(param1: "value1", param2: "value2"...)
```

My problem is with this first call. When I do this in any HAML file, it renders my helper. **Except if my file name is _search_form.html.haml.** Is that case, it returns `nil`.

If I put a raise error in the helper, I notice that my method isn't being called, but I am not able to find what is being called and why.

If I use the syntax on the second and third lines, it works as expected by calling my helper method.

So my question is: is this standard Rails behavior or a bug?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: I edited the question. By work, i mean : it call my helper function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Rails will look for a local variable with the same name as your partial, which may conflict with existing method names.

One way to get around this is to simply redefine the method inside your partial:

```
<% search_form = self.search_form %>
# Rest of the partial's code
```